# Exclude both rows one of them doesn't match criteria - self join?

Tags: mysql, join

I've got a table that stores a person's tea preference on any given date. ;)

```
customer_id, tea_preference,     date
     1        'yes please'    2011-01-01
     1        'no thanks'     2011-01-02
```

and I need to find customers that like tea within a given date range, eg:

```
SELECT * FROM customers
WHERE tea_preference = 'yes please'
AND date BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-01-03'
```

Now, that query will give one match, but if the customer doesn't like tea on one of dates within the range, I don't want any matches for that customer...

I've tried self joins, but either they aren't the answer or I'm not doing it right, as I can't seem to get the result set I'm after. Help?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
SELECT c1.* FROM customers c1
WHERE c1.tea_preference = 'yes please' 
AND c1.date BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-01-03'
AND NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT c2.* FROM customers c2 
    WHERE c2.tea_preference = 'no thanks'
    AND c2.date BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-01-03' 
    AND c1.custom_id = c2.customer_id)
```

Comment: +1, thanks. Not very efficient, but definitely got me headed in the right direction!

Comment: Glad it worked as inspiration :) Probably most efficient as a left join and a check for null in left table in the where clause